# When is the union of topologies a topology?

Tags: general-topology

The union of two topologies on some set may or may not be a topology. When is it a topology?

Comment: Here's an obvious sufficient condition: when one is contained in the other. But that's not a necessary condition.

Comment: I'd very much doubt there's any non-trivial condition, you would have to check these kinds of things on a case by case basis.

Comment: If $X$ has cardinality one or two then this result is true, otherwise it is false.  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Topologies_on_Singleton_or_Doubleton_is_Topology

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on a point set $X$.  That is, $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are subsets of the powerset of $X$, each indicating which subsets of $X$ should be called *open*.  Let $\tau = \tau_1 \cup \tau_2$.  In general $\tau$ is not a topology on $X$, but let's see which conditions are satisfied and which could fail:

(1)  $\emptyset \in \tau$.  True since $\emptyset \in \tau_1$ (and $\tau_2$).

(2)  $X \in \tau$.  True since $X \in \tau_1$ (and $\tau_2$).

(3)  Arbitrary unions of open sets are in $\tau$, that is,

$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I}} U_{\alpha} \in \tau.$$

Not true in general.  At best, I can partition the sets into those in $\tau_1$ and those in $\tau_2$ so that we have:

$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I}} U_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I} \cap \tau_1} U_{\alpha} \cup \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I} \cap \tau_2} U_{\alpha} = V \cup W,$$

where $V \in \tau_1$ and $W \in \tau_2$ because each $\tau_i$ is a topology.  But here's where we get stuck.  I have no guarantee that $V \cup W$ is in either $\tau_1$ or $\tau_2$, hence I can't place $V \cup W \in \tau$.

(4) Finite intersections of open sets are in $\tau$, that is,

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \tau.$$

Again, I could partition the sets according to $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ so that

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \tau = V \cap W,$$

for $V \in \tau_1$ and $W \in \tau_2$.  But unless $V \cap W \in \tau_1$ or $\tau_2$, I cannot find $V \cap W \in \tau = \tau_1 \cup \tau_2$.

So this leads to the necessary (and sufficient) conditions:  $\tau = \tau_1 \cup \tau_2$ is a topology if every pairwise union $U \cup V$ and intersection $U \cap V$ of open sets $U \in \tau_1$ and $V \in \tau_2$ lies in either $\tau_1$ or $\tau_2$.  Of course, this does not strike me as a very useful or easy condition to check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for an useful necessary and sufficient condition, but this makes me think there is no such thing.

Comment: I understand completely the failure of condition (4), but I don't understand the failure of condition (3). Do you think you could explain it? By definition $V \in \mathscr T_1$ and $W \in \mathscr T_2$, which seems like it should by definition of unions imply that $V \cup W \in \mathscr T_1 \cup \mathscr T_2 \equiv \mathscr T$...? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @SamBlattner The set $\mathscr{T}_{1} \cup \mathscr{T}_{2}$ consists of all \textit{sets} in $\mathscr{T}_{1}$ or $\mathscr{T}_{2}$. When one considers whether $V \cup W$ belongs to this union, we evaluate whether one of $\mathscr{T}_{1}$ or $\mathscr{T}_{2}$  contains $V \cup W$. You are mistakenly thinking (methinks) that one must evaluate whether, if $\mathscr{T}_{1} = \{ T_{1}, T_{2}, \dots \}$ and $\mathscr{T}_{2} = \{ T'_{1}, T'_{2}, \dots \}$, $V \cup W \in \{ T_{1} \cup T'_{1}, T_{1} \cup T'_{2}, \dots, T_{2} \cup T'_{1}, T_{2} \cup T'_{2}, \dots \}$

Answer (score 4):

Years late to answer this but:

There is actually a problem in Munkres related to this: prove for a family of topologies $\{\tau_\alpha \}$ on a set $X$ that there is a unique smallest topology containing all of the topologies in the family.

If you set $S = \{ U : U \in \tau_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha \}$ and consider the topology generated by $S$ (as a subbasis) I think this does the trick.  It also provides a less wordy sufficient and necessary condition to your question.